# How to inject Log4j2 ThreadContext values into Jersey's LoggingFeature

Tags: java, spring, jersey-2.0, log4j2, java.util.logging

I want to log Request/Response of my server in log files. I am using Springboot + jersey 2.x + log4j2. I registered jersey's LoggingFeature like this -

```
jerseyConfig.register(
    new LoggingFeature(
          java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(
                     LoggingFeature.DEFAULT_LOGGER_NAME),
          java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE,
          LoggingFeature.Verbosity.PAYLOAD_ANY,
          Integer.MAX_VALUE)
);
```

log4j2.xml

```
<!-- Jersey logger -->
<AsyncLogger name="org.glassfish" level="all" additivity="false">
    <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="off" />
    <AppenderRef ref="RollingFileIO" level="error" />
</AsyncLogger>
```

In pattern, I am injecting transaction-id with help of log4j2's `ThreadContext`. I have `log4j-jul 2.1` in my pom.xml, and I am running it with

`-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager` .

Things are working fine, only problem is, in jersey's logs, I am unable to insert transaction id. I tried utils logging with my custom code, and I am able to put transaction-id in it. But by the time jersey writes these logs, ThreadContext gets cleared and transaction-id values comes empty.

Comment: What do you mean "unable to insert transaction id"? Error?  Unclear on what API to use (or whether API exists)?

Comment: I meant, by the time jersey writes these logs, ThreadContext gets cleared by my code. For any http request, I generate transaction-id and put it in ThreadContext and clear it when response goes out. Jersey writes before and after of these events. I tried java.util.logging by my own logging, and it successfully puts transaction-id in logs.

Answer (score 0):

If the log flow is `JUL->log4j2->FooAppender->Layout->ThreadContext.pop` then

Per [Including the ThreadContext when writing logs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/thread-context.html):

> The PatternLayout provides mechanisms to print the contents of the ThreadContext Map and Stack.
>
> - Use `%X` by itself to include the full contents of the Map.
> - Use `%X{key}` to include the specified key.
> - Use `%x` to include the full contents of the Stack.

If the flow is `log4j2->JUL->FooHandler->Formatter->ThreadContext.pop` then you have to install or create a formatter that is aware of the `ThreadContext`. You also have make sure in this configuration that `log4j2->ThreadContext.pop->JUL->FooHandler->Formatter` is not happening as that would forget all of the information before it gets to `JUL`.

All of the examples in the documentation show the `ThreadContext` is set prior to invoking the logger.  Which means you have to set the `ThreadContext` prior to any Jersey code execution.

Comment: If I write my own utils logging, I am able to get values from ThreadContext. I am looking to find a way to set ThreadContext before jersey's code execution.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at Jersey in detail but from the problem description it seems that it has a thread model that makes working with `ThreadContext` difficult.

Fortunately Log4j 2.7 offers a facility to let you inject key-value pairs (like ID) into log events from another source than the ThreadContext. This was introduced to help with asynchronous frameworks like [Finagle](https://twitter.github.io/finagle/), so it may be useful for Jersey as well.

The Log4j2 manual briefly mentions this feature in the section on [Custom ContextDataInjectors](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html#Custom_ContextDataInjector).

If you want to use this facility you need to write a custom [`ContextDataInjector`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/ContextDataInjector.html) and tell Log4j to use that injector instead of the default one by specifying a [`ContextDataInjectorFactory`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/impl/ContextDataInjectorFactory.html). Your custom injector needs to get the key-value pairs from somewhere. In Jersey's case, would RequestContext.getProperty and setProperty be appropriate?